# Are either of these "Dungeons and Dragons"-related questions, good questions?

Tags: discussion

Is this a good question?

"Did "Dungeons and Dragons" give a new meaning to the word "Dungeon"? If so, what meaning was it?"

or would a better question be:

"How did the meaning of "Dungeons" in "Dungeons and Dragons" evolve from the meaning of Dungeon as a Prison (Cell)?"

Made a Question on RPG.SE: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67422/why-do-dd-and-other-rpgs-players-use-dungeon-to-mean-the-places-they-go-to

This meta question is also asked here: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7158/has-this-been-asked-before-how-did-dungeon-evolved-to-mean-place-where-adv

And here: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5733/are-these-good-questions-what-does-dungeon-mean-in-dungeons-and-dragons/5735#5735

[Apparently](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5735/21941), the "Dungeons" of "Dungeons and Dragons" is meant to be evocative, instead of descriptive... I think that's what Doppelgreener's saying.

Comment: Both questions assume a knowledge of what *Dungeon* means in "Dungeons and Dragons". Certainly I had always assumed it took its ordinary meaning of subterranean prison.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - ... I want to agree... But given the content of "Dungeons and Dragons"... Does that actually work?... I guess the adventurers are going into dungeons that are made to hold monsters?

Comment: So is the question you want to ask asserting that a D&D "dungeon" is not a prison and when did that word acquire its esoteric meaning, or is it asking whether a D&D "dungeon" really is a dungeon/prison? Currently neither is a good question, because you need to define what a D&D "dungeon" actually **is.**

Comment: The definition of *dungeon* in D&D by Google: *(in fantasy role-playing games) **a labyrinthine subterranean setting***. – What's the etymology of this definition?

Comment: @Mazura - Hey Mazura! Great work! I wouldn't have thought to cite Google!

Comment: Dungeon as "monster filled cave" instead of "structure built to hold criminals"

Comment: I'd say what we have here is the makings of a good question, but *i* don't run around casting close votes so...

Comment: Is there a reason that there isn't a question for this on English.usage SE?
Seems usage question.

Comment: *Dungeon* has been historically used in the pen-and-paper fantasy rôle-playing community as a general term for any sort of of mapped-out venue with accompanying descriptions in someone’s *campaign*, which is another special word. It is usually a built-up structure of some sort. It is seldom a prison.  It may be a labyrinth whether underground or otherwise. It could be a castle or manor house or a town. Various other outdoor situations are possible. Since the success of the early Giant and Drow modules, *module* has been used for the assorted, pre-determined collection.